# How to avoid Cyclic Dependencies when using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am relatively new to the concept dependency injection, so I am unsure about how it prevents cyclic dependencies. Let's say I have followed projects (the sample project structure might not be good but please bear with me)

> Project A:
>
> - Domain Layer
> - IRepository
>
> Project B:
>
> - RepositoryImpl --> implement IRepository interface

In this case Project B will need to reference Project A. But to set up Project A, let's say Unity Container, Project A will need to reference Project B in order to have something like this in the Unity Config.

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
```

But doesn't this introduce cyclic dependency? Or is it I'm having wrong understanding in either Dependency Injection or cyclic Dependency? or even both?

Comment: I think you mean "cyclic" instead of "acyclic". Dependency graphs should be acyclic, which means the graph is _directed_ and has no cycles.

Comment: ahhh yes, it should be cyclic, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an important concept here, which is the concept of the Composition Root. The best and most elaborate description of what a Composition Root is, can be found [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). To summarize:

> A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.

As the article explains:

> Most classes use *Constructor Injection*. By doing this they push the responsibility of the creation of their dependencies up to their consumer. That consumer -again- push the responsibility of the creation of its dependencies up as well.
>
> We can’t delay the creation of our classes indefinitely. There must be a location where we create our object graphs. You should concentrate this creation into a single area of your application. This place is called the *Composition Root*.

Only the application's entry point contains a Composition Root, any other libraries in application *do not*.

This means that the Domain Layer *itself* does not register its types into the DI Container—only the startup project does this. When you do this, the Domain Layer will therefore *not* have to depend the Data Access Library (your Project B).

Both the [first](https://manning.com/seemann/) edition (chapter 2) and [second edition](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (chapter 3) of the book Dependency Injection in .NET contain a elaborate discussion of an example that is *very close* to the application structure given in your question. The previously referenced Composition Root article is an excerpt from the second edition. The first chapter can be read for free [online](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1).